# Multi-Table Sorting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I'd like to be able to sort on a field that is in a linked table, Artist Name then by Release Title when viewing the albums in a category.

Database:

In the Categories table, artists are linked by ID

In the `Category#Show`, I have `@releases = Shelf.joins(:artists).find(@shelf.shelf_discogs_id).releases.order('release_title ASC').page(params[:page])`

The above code works to sort by the Release Title, however, I can’t find a way to make it sort by the Artist Name, which is part of the Artists table.

The `joins(:artists)` does add the correct line in the console to link correctly (from what I can tell)

```sql
SELECT  "shelves".*
FROM "shelves"
  INNER JOIN "releases"
    ON "releases"."shelf_id" = "shelves"."shelf_discogs_id"
  INNER JOIN "artists"
    ON "artists"."artist_discogs_id" = "releases"."artist_id"
WHERE "shelves"."shelf_discogs_id" = $1
LIMIT $2
```

Model for Releases

```
class Release < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :shelf
  belongs_to :artist
  belongs_to :record_label
  belongs_to :record_location
  has_many :tracks

end
```

Model for Artists

```
class Artist < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :releases
  has_many :tracks
  has_many :shelves, through: :releases

end
```

Any ideas how I can achieve what I’m looking to do?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it specifying the `name` column is in the artists table:

```
Shelf
  .find(@shelf.shelf_discogs_id)
  .releases
  .joins(:artist)
  .order('releases.release_title ASC, artists.artist_name ASC')
  .page(params[:page])
```

Comment: I'm getting an error ....

`PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "artists"
LINE 1: ...."shelf_id" = $1 ORDER BY releases.release_title, artists.ar...
                                                             ^
: SELECT  "releases".* FROM "releases" WHERE "releases"."shelf_id" = $1 ORDER BY releases.release_title, artists.artist_name LIMIT $2 OFFSET $3`

Comment: Can you add the models you're using to see their relationships? It's clear you need to add artists to the joins clause, but I don't see how they're related.

Comment: will add to main post

Comment: See the updated answer. `joins` is right after you're getting the relases, and the relationship is belongs_to, so `artist` is in its singular way.

Comment: same error `PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column artists.name does not exist
LINE 1: ...elf_id" = $1 ORDER BY releases.release_title ASC, artists.na...
                                                             ^
: SELECT  "releases".* FROM "releases" INNER JOIN "artists" ON "artists"."artist_discogs_id" = "releases"."artist_id" WHERE "releases"."shelf_id" = $1 ORDER BY releases.release_title ASC, artists.name ASC LIMIT $2 OFFSET $3`

Comment: Isn't the same error, are you sure the artists table has a name column, can you add your db/schema.rb file?

Comment: its `artist_name` but I was changing the field name

Answer (score 1):

I'd try

```
Shelf.find(@shelf.shelf_discogs_id).releases.joins(:artists).order('releases.release_title ASC, artists.name ASC')
```

You perform 2 queries - first you find a shelf with

```
shelf = Shelf.find(@shelf.shelf_discogs_id)
```

then all the releases for this shelf with

```
shelf.releases.joins(:artist).order('releases.release_title ASC, artists.name ASC')
```

you don't need the `join` in the first query, because `artists` are not used there

Comment: Different Error to the other suggestion .. `Can't join 'Release' to association named 'artists'; perhaps you misspelled it?` but the `has_many` and `belongs_to` are written and work

Comment: fixed `artists` -> `artist` (good that you shown relationships)

Comment: Works, but i'm choosing the other answer, as correct as it only uses one query Thanks for helping :D

Comment: The other one uses 2 queries as well (first finding a shelf, then fetching releases)